# Phonegap 3 - Call Cordova methods in hosted application

Tags: android, cordova

I'm porting a Phonegap 2.7 application to Phonegap 3. The application is hosted, so phonegap loads an external url instead of a local html. This hosted webapp loads `cordoba.js`, however I'm unable to use plugins such as splashscreen and notifications from the hosted webapp:

```
navigator.splashscreen.hide(); 
// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'hide' of undefined

navigator.notification.vibrate(500);
// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'vibrate' of undefined
```

The hosted application required the same Cordova file that was included when I created the Phonegap 3 project. Why am I unable to use this API's? This worked fine on Phonegap 2.7.

**UPDATE:** Events are triggered correctly:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', callback, false);
```

`callback` is correctly called, so there is some kind of cordova interaction already. Problem seems plugins.

Comment: Is there any web url for Cordova based hosted app? I would like to look for some samples. Which allows some client-server communication too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the plugin directly with cordova.exec. it goes like this:

```
cordova.exec(function(response){}, function(errorText){}, "PluginName", "method", []) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Cordova exec()!`

I wonder if your cordova.js file just doesn't have the navigator.splashscreen object. In Cordova 3.0, all of the plugins were separated out, and the cordova.js file just became the bridge code. When the app runs, it loads all of the plugin .js files via ajax - see the `cordova_plugins.js` file in a built project. As it loads these files, Cordova will fix up the namespaces for you, so that navigator.splashscreen namespace actually maps to the splashscreen js code.  I'm betting you are not loading this cordova_plugins.js file which means the clobbering isn't working.

It's still working because the bridge code works. When you use exec() you're just running the command that navigator.splashscreen.hide does: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/blob/master/www/splashscreen.js#L26

If I were you, I'd try to rebuild the app the new Cordova 3.x way, with the [cordova cli](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface). That way you won't have to actually call the exec function manually which seems pretty brittle (the `exec()` probably won't change, but it seems like a pain looking up the exec calls for every plugin interaction you need.)

BTW I'm not sergio on irc, so feel free to give him the answer if he posts since he answered your question first. I'm just trying to explain why that happens and why it doens't work for you anymore - basically, 2.7 and 3.x are pretty different in terms of plugins.

Comment: I just noticed in my server logs that `cordova_pluginsjs` is indeed being loaded: `200 GET /dashboard/phonegap/cordova_plugins.js (192.168.1.9) 13.38ms` however that file does not exists in my filesystem (where the server says it loaded it). I noticed it is created at build time per platform, so how is the server loading it? I s it created dynamically? If it is indeed being loaded, why can't I access those features?

Comment: What are the contents of `cordova_plugins.js`? It should contain a list of your plugins and their locations, as well as which namespace it should clobber. Then later it should load up these files - is it finding these plugin .js files as well?

Comment: There is no `cordova_plugins.js` in my filesystem, even when the server does return the resource with a 200 HTTP Code. Thats why I though it was generated dynamically

Comment: Well 200 GET just means that the request was successful, not that the server sent anything back. If you fire up logcat and browser to that page with your app, I'm betting it the request will come back with  404. 

cordova_plugins.js is generated by the build tools at build time based on the plugins that you have installed with `cordova plugin add ...`, it doesn't get generated dynamically though at run time.